# Use the content of a counter in cline

Tags: tables, rules, counters

consider the following example:

```
\newcounter{cnt}
\setcounter{cnt}{3}
\begin{tabular}{l|l|l|}
    \cline{2-3} 
    a & b & c
\end{tabular}
```

I have a package that generates tables with a variable amount of columns. I want to use the `cline` command to draw a horizontal line that does not include the first cell

The amount of cells is stored in a counter (example counter *cnt* in the example). Is there any way I can use the content of the counter in the cline argument?

Comment: `\cline{2-\value{cnt}}` does the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `\thecnt`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{cnt}
\setcounter{cnt}{3}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{l|l|l|}
    \cline{2-\thecnt} 
    a & b & c
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```